# DataStudio settings in the manifest are deleted

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

When I implement a new project or update automatically the DataStudio settings in the manifest are deleted.

Does anyone know why this happens?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This seems to be an issue related to Apps Script's new editor.

I suggest you open an issue on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=985382&template=1531277).

*A workaround* for this is to switch to the old editor.

Answer (score 0):

+1 I've been having the exact same issue with new UI. I keep switching back to the legacy UI and reverting the Manifests version back.

I think some update must have happened on the backend to cause this but I'm not sure what. Will start using the legacy UI to deploy for now.

In the meantime I've opened this issue with the google issue tracker you linked above
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194244611

Comment: It was already reported, this is the tracking link according to Google. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194030371